# I can't submit my CS50 code solution using terminal on mac

Tags: cs50

So I am trying to submit my `CS50` `(https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2020/tracks/mobile/android/fiftygram/)` in my terminal by using `submit50 cs50/problems/2020/x/tracks/android/fiftygram`. I have installed `pip3` and `CS50` but I keep getting an error zsh:

```
command not found: submit50
```

Please help! How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You also need to install submit50 itself. The instructions are here:

https://cs50.readthedocs.io/submit50/#installation

Edit: given the comment that OP has done this, try updating pip. It may be a version issue after switching to zsh. Alternatively, if you still have another shell use that.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/557185/pip-error-after-changing-from-bash-to-zsh

Comment: I did install submit50 by pip3 install submit50. And it is installed as I can see it when I do pip3 show submit50. But I when try to submit my work, I get zsh: command not found: submit50

Answer (score 0):

I had to **add the `submit50` command to PATH**.

I did this by adding the bin folder to the PATH.

---

For Ubuntu:

1. Open `~/.bashrc` with a text editor. For example, run `nano ~/.bashrc`
2. Add this to the end of the file

```bash
# ~/.bashrc file

# ...

export PATH=$PATH:~/.local/bin
```

3. Restart the terminal
4. Run `submit50` to test